# Fieldset per form or fieldset per field group?

Tags: html

If I have a data capture form with either tapstrips and or two columns or input fields, is it better to have one fieldset per group of fields, i.e. column, or one fieldset for the whole form and other grouping semantics per group? I like the fieldset per group because of the legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of a `fieldset`, according to the [W3](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/fieldset):

> ...represents a set of form controls optionally grouped under a common name.

I take this to mean that it contains a group of similar form elements together (based on the data they're meant to gather), for example the contact details of a user, or the payment details.

If you have a small form, that collects, for example, the log-in details then I would, personally, either use only one `fieldset` for the whole `form` *or* omit the `fieldset` entirely.

But there is no official requirement beyond using your own common sense in the use of relevant elements. Though it may, to my mind, offer a semantic grouping which may aid those users with particular accessibility software.